How to run node v20.x on CentOs 7.9?
I've been stuck on this issue for too long. Basically I have a node v20.x app that I'd like to run on a CentOS 7.9 server. For reasons, we do not wish to upgrade the OS now but I'm sure there must be a way to run node v20?
I've built and installed GCC 10.3 from source, which I've read was required for node 20 but still getting errors.
These are the errors I currently have on running node .
node .
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)

node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.9 not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found (required by node)
Would this be possible? And how do I proceed?
Also, I'm a bit careful not to interupt the apache / mysql server running in the mean time.
I've read that upgrading glibc on CentOS 7 can be extremely dangerous making the system unbootable?
Is there really no safe way around this?

What is the GlibC version in the repository/archive?

I decided to go around this issue using Docker.
Actually it suits my case quite well!

Installing npm on Centos 7
This approach is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921215/getting-glibc-2-28-not-found/77247394#77247394 and https://serverfault.com/questions/894625/safely-upgrade-glibc-on-centos-7/894689#894689 but for CentOS@^7.
Taking the current LTS version of node@^22 that requires glibc@2.28 since node@^18 as example:

Install pre-built gcc@8.3.1 from centos-release-scl:

yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-8-{gcc,make}


Enter the subshell with gcc@8.3.1

scl enable devtoolset-8 # enter scl subshell
which gcc # /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/gcc
gcc --version # gcc version 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3) (GCC)


Grab the source of glibc@2.28:

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.xz
tar xvf glibc-2.28.tar.xz


Build the glibc@2.28:

cd glibc-2.28
mkdir build
cd build

../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.28
time make -j"$(nproc)"
make install
exit # exit the scl subshell


Grab the source of gcc@6.5.0 for building its libstdc++@6.0.22 as node@22 is requiring versionized symbol with GLIBCX_3.4.22:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360886/nodejs-circleci-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164795/error-with-npm-sqlite3-library-after-upgrading-to-node-12-glibcxx-3-4-21-not
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167639/glibcx-3-4-21-not-found
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1774
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424974/anaconda-importerror-usr-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-fo

And according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found/49363515#49363515 , the first version that exporting symbol version GLIBCX_3.4.22 is between gcc@6.1.0 and gcc@7.1.0 so we choose to build the latest gcc@6.5.0 within its 6.x series
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.5.0/gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz
tar xvf gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz

scl enable devtoolset-8 # enter scl subshell
cd gcc-6.5.0
mkdir build
cd build


It's possible to compile only the libstdc++.so.6 without build the whole GCC: How to compile libstdc++ with specific compiler option?

../libstdc++-v3/configure --prefix=/opt/libstdc++-6.0.22 --disable-multilib
time make -j"$(nproc)"

But the built artifact won't export symbol _ZSt11__once_call that Node is importing, this can be verified by
strings src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 | grep _ZSt11__once_call

that outputs nothing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405588/using-clang-with-built-libstdc-produces-undefined-symbol-zst15-once-callable

So we'll still have to build the complete GCC collection:

cd ..
rm -rf build
./contrib/download_prerequisites

mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-6.5.0 --disable-multilib


Depend on the performance of your hardware, this may take hours and many GiBs of disk space: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html

time make -j"$(nproc)"
cd x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3 # only install libstdc++.so
make install
exit # exit the scl subshell


If you are in hurry and trusting some randomly uploaded binrary, extract the path gcc63-c++-6.3.0-1.el7.x86_64.cpio\.\usr\local\gcc63\lib64\libstdc++.so.6.0.22 from gcc63-c++-6.3.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm that uploaded by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 and store it under /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22.
On Windows you may use NanaZip to unarchive *.rpm and *.cpio files.

Symlinking the built libstdc++.so.6.0.22 under /opt/glibc-2.28/lib if you don't want to define a shell var LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-6.5.0/lib64 node for everytime running node:


ln -s /opt/gcc-6.5.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/libstdc++.so.6


Download binrary of patchelf for patching the node executable:

wget https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/releases/download/0.18.0/patchelf-0.18.0-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf patchelf-0.18.0-x86_64.tar.gz


Download the node itself:

wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v22.12.0/node-v22.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-v22.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
cd node-v22.12.0-linux-x64/bin


Patch node:

~/patchelf/bin/patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 node # required
~/patchelf/bin/patchelf --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.28/lib:/usr/lib64 node # optional, similar to 9.


Enjoy:

./node
console.log(1);
process.exit(2);
echo $?

Kickstart script:
# https://gist.github.com/mohanpedala/1e2ff5661761d3abd0385e8223e16425
# https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105
set -euxo pipefail

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.xz
tar xvf glibc-2.28.tar.xz

yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-8-{gcc,make}
scl enable devtoolset-8
    cd glibc-2.28
    mkdir build
    cd build

    ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.28
    make -j"$(nproc)"
    make install
exit

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.5.0/gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz
tar xvf gcc-6.5.0.tar.xz

scl enable devtoolset-8
    cd gcc-6.5.0
    ./contrib/download_prerequisites

    mkdir build
    cd build
    ../configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-6.5.0 --disable-multilib

    # depend on the performance of your hardware, this may take hours and many GiBs of disk space
    time make -j"$(nproc)"
    make install
exit

ln -s /opt/gcc-6.5.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/libstdc++.so.6

wget https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/releases/download/0.18.0/patchelf-0.18.0-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf patchelf-0.18.0-x86_64.tar.gz

wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v22.12.0/node-v22.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-v22.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
cd node-v22.12.0-linux-x64/bin

# https://serverfault.com/questions/894625/safely-upgrade-glibc-on-centos-7/894689#894689
~/patchelf/bin/patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 node
~/patchelf/bin/patchelf --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.28/lib:/usr/lib64 node

./node

